# How to add NSManagedObjectContext with ConcerrencyType in swift 3?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

In my app i have tasks that download data and save them to CoreData. After i migrated to swift 3 it started throwing exceptions while saving data, at a random time. As i understood, it can happen if i use one context for all operations. Now i created another context with concurrency type, everything works without errors, but nothing is saved to .sqlite file :)
Here's how i create context:

```
static let context : NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
static let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)

static func declare()
{
    AixmParser.privateContext.parent = AixmParser.context
}
```

I save data like this:

```
    do{
        try privateContext.save()
    }
    catch{
    }
```

Do i have to add something to declaration or to the core data stack?

Update: Core Data stack below.

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        container.viewContext.perform({
            // actions upon the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType NSManagedObjectContext for this container
        })

    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see how did you set up your core data stack. The `save()` saves the values and push it to the `parentContext`. You have to chain the `save()` in a `while` loop to the last context with no parent. This context is directly connected to the `persistentStoreCoordinator`.

Comment: @New16, i added my core data stack. How should i chain `save()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first is that you have to create a link from the `privateContext` to the `NSPersistentContainer`'s `viewContext`. So, while creating the private, 
    `privateContext`, `privateContext.parentContext = viewContext`. While saving 
        `let context = privateContext
         while(context != nil) {
            context.save()
            context = context.privateContext
         }` 
This will work.
I am not sure why did you get the errors in the first place.

Comment: Isn't it the same? I create context, which is viewContext, and then set it as parentContext for privateContext.

About saving - i should add it to Core Data stack or just replace my saving code everywhere?

Comment: Create an `extension` of `NSManagedObjectContext` to include the propagation of the `save()` method. So, instead of calling `save()` call like `saveAndPropagate()`.

Comment: `context = context.privateContext`
Did you mean `context.parent` here?

Comment: Okay. `extension NSManagedObject { func privateContext() -> self { let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.privateQueueConcurrencyType)  context.parentContext =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext return context}  func saveAndPropagate() { let context = privateContext
         while(context != nil) {
            context.save()
            context = context.privateContext
         }}  } `

Comment: i read some documentation and did nearly the same, made all requests to CoreData in singleton and added a func to create context for background. Thanks!